# Bootstrap modal not showing after copy and paste

Tags: html, css

Im using the latest bootstrap and i went to make a second modal for my register link and i copied and pasted the exact code i had for the login which worked but for some reason the register one wont. It only dims the background but doesnt pop the modal up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Yeti Draft</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div id = "container">
    <div id = "header">
    <h1>Maybe the logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div id = "navbar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <div id = navStart>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Winners!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li></div>
                <div id = "login"><li><a href="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
                <li class = "sign"><a href="#registerModal" data-toggle="modal">Sign Up</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id = "content">
    </div>
    <div id = "footer">
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Login modal -->    
        <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class = "modal-dialog">
                <div class = "modal-content">
                    <div class = "modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3> 
                    </div>    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">    
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div> 

    <!-- Register modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class = "modal-dialog">
                <div class = "modal-content">
                    <div class = "modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h3> 
                    </div>    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">    
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div> 


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you in the same folder than your older file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed to close the following

1. Login modal :

`<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" aria-hidden="true">`

**`</div>`**

2. Register modal :

`<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" aria-hidden="true">`

**`</div>`**

Answer (score 0):

The register-modal div is placed inside the login-modal div.(You have missed one of the closing div tags for the login modal.) Please put the register-modal outside the login-modal. It would work perfectly.

Cheers!